# fetch id and store it in hidden text field on autocomplete select using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

this is my view code

```
<input type="text" name="chname" id="chrname" placeholder="church name" />
```

this is my controller code

```
function auto_comp(){
   $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    if(!$q) return;
    $res=$this->churchmodel->auto_compt($q);
    if($res){
      foreach($res as $row){
        //echo row->chid;echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row->chid."\" />";echo row->churchname."\n"; 
      }
    }
  }
```

this is my model code

```
function auto_compt($name){
$val="%".$name."%";
$query=$this->db->query("select distinct name as churchname, id as chid from church where name like '$val'");
if($query->num_rows>0){
    return $query->result();
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

jquery code

```
 $().ready(function() {
  $("#chrname").autocomplete("localhost/deeps/genting/index.php/church/auto_comp", {
     width: 260,
     matchContains: true,
     selectFirst: false
  });  
 });
```

here its working perfectly but i need to fetch corresponding id on particular select so that i can easily store the id of an selected value. please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chrname").autocomplete("localhost/deeps/genting/index.php/church/auto_comp", {
  width: 260,
  matchContains: true,
  selectFirst: false,
  select: function (event) {
   alert(event.target.id)   // fetch your id here
  }
 });  
});
```

Comment: How are you fetching your data here? where is `source` in your `autocomplete`?

Comment: i need to show name to user when user click the name i need to save the corresponding id in db. this is the coding where i get the name and id from db (i.e see controller i used echo to print name and id) that name and id not enough i need to seperate it in front end. my problem is what im echoing in controller that alone showing in display that means i cant use id and name seperately both coming in same text box so that i cant save id in db.